# What should I do if I went to sleep and missed Fajr?

Tags: salat, salat-qada, fajr

I got up for fajr time and I were tired so I decided to go to sleep  but I put an alarm on. When I woke up it was passed fajr time.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offer Qada.

> من نسي صلاة أو نام عنها فكفارتها أن يصليها إذا ذكرها
>
> He who forgets the prayer, or he slept (and it was omitted), its expiation is (only) that he should observe it when he remembers it.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684c)</sup>